# how to parse Box object in MP4 Parser in Apache Tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika

i want to extract metadata from mp4 files using **apache tika**...
i tried the below code..i get the contents in **MovieHeaderBox** as follows

```
MovieHeaderBox[creationTime=3438936505;modificationTime=3438936505;timescale=90000;duration=17859600;rate=1.0;volume=1.0;matrix0=65536;matrix1=0;matrix2=0;matrix3=0;matrix4=65536;matrix5=0;matrix6=0;matrix7=0;matrix8=1073741824;nextTrackId=3]
```

code i used:

```
for(Box b : moov.getBoxes()) 
    {

        if (b instanceof MovieHeaderBox) 
        { 


            System.out.println(((MovieHeaderBox) b).toString());
        }

     }
```